# Integrate ASP.NET MVC with react vite

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, vite

I want to integrate ASP.NET MVC and react and vite  I see this [example](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2023/02/11/aspnet-core-react-with-vitejs/). this is work but I want to render react inside root of url not /app.

When I comment base:/app in viteConfig and change var spaPath = "/app"; to var spaPath = "";

My react page renders, but I cant call controller. can u please help me?